# Angular Google Maps ui-gmap-markers slow performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

`<ui-gmap-markers>` is intended for a big amount of markers and it does work fine when everything is static. However when I try to change the option of a marker (for example changing a marker's icon when hovering), it takes a noticeable amount of time to update, nearly half a second which is not optimal.

I am displaying over one thousand icons with only a few showing in the screen at any time. This might be relevant:

```
<ui-gmap-markers models="markers" idKey="'idKey'" options="'options'" coords="'location'"></ui-gmap-markers>
```

Is there a way to speed it up? Maybe the Angular Google Maps library just wasn't designed for handling a large amount of markers? It was quite responsive using the Google Maps library directly in my previous projects.